# To read date time format( 2017-01-12t141206) through pyspark

Tags: pyspark, timestamp

I have a requirement where I want to read a column which gets time stamp in format( 2017-01-12t141206) through pyspark. I tried a couple of functions mentioned on different forums eg. strptime, strftime and few more  but none helped. Could someone pls guide me with relevant info? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.to_timestamp`** (or) `from_unixtime`,`unix_timestamp` functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
#using to_timestamp function
spark.sql("""select to_timestamp("2017-01-12t141206","yyyy-MM-dd't'HHmmss") as ts""").show()

#or using from_unixtime, unix_timestamp,cast(timestamp) functions
spark.sql("""select timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2017-01-12t141206","yyyy-MM-dd't'HHmmss"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")) as ts""")

#or using unix_timestmap, cast to timestamp
spark.sql("""select timestamp(unix_timestamp("2017-01-12t141206","yyyy-MM-dd't'HHmmss")) as ts""").show()

#+-------------------+
#|                 ts|
#+-------------------+
#|2017-01-12 14:12:06|
#+-------------------+
```

Comment: I upvoted, but on this forum, a reputation of 15 is required to change the count publically.